# jquery - how to call a function with parameters inside a widget-factory plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parameters

I want to call a function inside my jquery-plugin (widget-factory based).

Looks like this:

```
(function( $, window) {
    $.widget("mobile.multiview",$.mobile.widget, {
        stackUp: function (source, event, data) {
             ...
        }
    }
}) (jQuery,this);
```

I want to call *stackUp* from outside of the plugin. The problem: I don't know how to pass the parameters correctly. This does not work:

```js
$('#trigger').multiview("stackUp('pagination', fakeEvent, fakeData)");
```

Can somebody point me to the correcty syntax of calling a public function inside a plugin and passing along parameters?

**UPDATE:**

I can call the function like this:

```
$('#trigger').multiview('stackUp');
```

but how can I pass the parameters?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, after endless meddling, the parameters or arguments are passed like this:

```
$("#trigger").multiview('stackUp','pagination', fakeEvent, fakeData );
```

You just have to add parameters after the function separated by comma. Hope this helps someone else, too.

Comment: what is ``#trigger`` referring to here? :S

Comment: @OZZIE: element with id of `trigger` but this was some time ago. Hope still helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with `jquery` but try this:

```js
$("#trigger").multiview(function() { stackUp('pagination', fakeEvent, fakeData); });
```

This is an anonymous function which will be executed on need with your static and dynamic parameters.

Comment: hm. can't get stackUp to fire like this.

Comment: Maybe it is the missing quotes. I'll add them.

Comment: Your allonymous function is nice, but never fired in my script. I found out the widgety way. See my answer. Thanx for help!

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know how that plugin extends and exposes its functions but I would guess you could try one of the following:

```
$.mobile.widget.stackUp.apply($('#trigger'), ['pagination', fakeEvent, fakeData]);
$.mobile.multiview.apply($('#trigger'), ['pagination', fakeEvent, fakeData]);
```

However its entirely possible that they don't expose that method. Do you have the code somewhere?

**UPDATE**

After actually finding out what this plugin is I read up on the docs and you should be able todo:

```
$('#trigger').stackUp(...)
```

View source here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/default.html - and look at the `random` function that is defined.

Alternatively you could just define the function in a more global scope and then use it as part of the config object and when you want to apply it to specific elements.

Comment: that returns: result of expression '$.mobile.widget.stackUp'[undefined] is not an object. Hold up. let me try again. Nah. doesn't work.

Comment: @frequent see my updated response. Only diff is you're doing `$.widget("mobile.multiview",$.mobile.widget, {..` and the example is `$.widget("mobile.multiview", {..`